# git is telling me all my files are new when they've been added and staged

Tags: git

git is telling me all 300 files that I've been adding/staging/committing all along are now new.

The latest unstaged modified and deleted files were correct,  I did a

```
 git add .
 git add . -A
```

but neither resolved the 300 new files it still sees.

kinda strange, like my repo has been destroyed or corrupted.  I had a fair amount of changes since last staging and commit, and as I said it saw these as modified or deleted.

ETA:

git status is showing (after I did my above commands)

```
 [(master) +300 ~0 -0]>
```

Comment: What is `git status` showing? This does seem odd.

Comment: What about `git status`?

Comment: you can always reset your git repo to earlier, but sounds like you have changes staged - have you look at git-diff to see what has changed?

Comment: can I just tell it to ignore these "new" files so I can commit my correct modifications and deletions?

Comment: you can do git -m "COMMIT MESSAGE" /path/to/file /path/to/file2 to only commit these files.

Comment: does the commit you did show up in the log?

Comment: when I do git log I get "fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to recover would be to:

- do a fresh clone of the repo
- copy over all the working tree (not its `.git` subdirectory) of the corrupted repo over the newly cloned and checked out working tree.
- Let git detect the *changes* (as opposed to new files)

Answer (score 0):

I had a scenario where **I changed the permissions for the project's directory and all files.**

After that, it showed that **every file is a new one.**

So I `git stash` my **"changes"** and went on.
Or you can commit the changes as well.

Hope this helps someone with my case.

Cheers.